# Node JS showing older version while creating the application

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to upgrade my existing angular project from angular 8 to angular 13. and my current node version is 15.3.0.

so it was showing error to upgrade node version to >=16 then i upgraded node to 16.10 . now when I am running command to update @angular/cli its throwing error like node js version 15.3.0 detected,

Even while creating new app same error is coming.

I uninstalled the old node 15.3.0 and installed new version 16.10 but still its showing same error.

But when we run node -v its showing 16.10 ,same when we open node js command prompt.

Only for the project creation / update angular cli it shows version 15.3.0 detected.

is there any specific reason ?

Node js command prompt shows::
[image]

but while creating app shows error::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try closing the terminal and open it again as administrator. had the same issue and it worked for me well.

otherwise you could try installing node via nvm (Node Version Manager):

todo:

1. Install nvm [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. run `nvm install 16`
3. check if version is installed with: `nvm ls`
4. switch default version to `nvm alias default 16.10.0`
5. check current version with: `node -v`

if its printing your desired version it should work well.

Comment: still not working for me

Comment: Make sure to restart your terminal after making the changes...